React component with FaceLivenessDetector works locally but fails to connect in AWS Amplify deployment
I developed a React component using AWS Amplify's FaceLivenessDetector, and I embedded this component into an Angular project. The functionality works perfectly in my local environment, and all requests related to the liveness detection are successfully executed.
However, after deploying the project to AWS Amplify, the FaceLivenessDetector keeps showing "reconnecting" and fails to complete its operation. No errors are displayed in the browser console, and the network tab in DevTools does not show any related requests being made in production.
Here's an overview of the setup:

Local environment: The component works as expected, and I can see the network requests in the browser's DevTools.
localhost requests
Production environment (AWS Amplify): The component continuously reconnects and does not show any network activity related to FaceLivenessDetector.
requests in deploy environment

Additional Details:

Frameworks: React (for the component) and Angular (for the main project).
Deployment: AWS Amplify.
No visible errors in the console or logs.

Steps I've tried so far:

Ensured the same AWS configuration (e.g., sessionId, region) is being used in both environments.
Checked IAM permissions for rekognition:CreateFaceLivenessSession and rekognition:GetFaceLivenessSessionResults.

